# Creating File and opening in Excel stops the ability to update the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using the following code to create an HTML table, save it to an XLS file and then open it in Excel.

```
    public void ExportToSpreadsheet(DataTable table, string name)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.Write("<table border=1>");

        context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            context.Response.Write("<tr>");
            context.Response.Write("<td width=47>" + row[1].ToString().Replace(";", string.Empty) + "</td>");
            context.Response.Write("<td width=47>" + row[2].ToString().Replace(";", string.Empty) + "</td>");
            context.Response.Write("<td width=110>" + row[3].ToString().Replace(";", string.Empty) + "</td>");
            context.Response.Write("<td width=75>" + row[4].ToString().Replace(";", string.Empty) + "</td>");
            context.Response.Write("<td width=285>" + row[5].ToString().Replace(";", string.Empty) + "</td>");
            context.Response.Write("<td width=61>" + row[6].ToString().Replace(";", string.Empty) + "</td>");

            context.Response.Write("</tr>");
            context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        context.Response.Write("</table>");
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name + ".xls");
        context.Response.End(); 
    }
```

Now this code works great, however, it is called from a button, and i wish to refresh some info on the page where that button exists after the report is run, but any code after the ExportToSpreadsheet method is completely ignored.

so when i do:

```
 ExportToSpreadsheet(dt, "MyReport");
 PopulateLastRun();
```

I can put a breakpoint on PopulatetoLastRun(), and it will never get there.  Can anyone tell me why?  is there a way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling `context.Response.End()` method on current response none of the code will be executed after that.

so inorder to flush the file use below code instead of calling `end()`.

```
context.Response.Flush();
```

Comment: If I do a flush instead of an end, it causes the page that I am trying to update to be opened by excel instead of the file created.